# OnMouseWheel gives wrong zDelta when doing a big motion on an hyper scroll mouse

Tags: visual-c++, scroll, mfc, mousewheel

I think this bug is only reproducible with an hyper scroll mouse, a mouse which allows to do a big movement of its wheel. For instance mine is Logitech M-U0007.

I am using the wheel to define the diameter of a circle attached to the cursor, which lower limit is 4mm and upper limit is 50mm.

If I am at the 50 mm now, and do a big movement **UP**, sometimes the function will provide a **NEGATIVE** `zDelta`, which is obviously wrong and the new diameter will be 4mm, which I don't it to be.

The same happens in the reverse situation.

If I am at the 4 mm now, and do a big movement **DOWN**, sometimes the function will provide a **POSITIVE** `zDelta`, which is obviously wrong and the new diameter will be 50mm, which I don't it to be.

The prototype of function to respond to the `ON_WM_MOUSEWHEEL()` event is

```
 OnMouseWheel(UINT nFlags, short zDelta, CPoint pt)
```

where it seems to me it is a limitation of the `zDelta` resolution, due to the fact it is a `short` type variable.

May be the reason is the MFC's internal source code to respond to the mouse wheel was made eternities before the idea of a mouse which allows very big wheel movement even lightened up inside the head of its creator(s).

So, is there a way to overcome this limitation?

Comment: It is up to the mouse manufacturer to do something reasonable when they create a device that exceeds what is possible on Windows.  And it certainly can't ever be anything bigger than a 16-bit value, given that WM_MOUSEWHEEL encodes it in the upper 16 bits of WPARAM.  Logitech, meh, their software has never stopped sucking yet.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't have any Logitech software installed. The mouse is transmitting directly its events to the OS without any middle layer.

Comment: MFC merely calls [GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646254.aspx) on the *wParam* it received in its [WM_MOUSEWHEEL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645617.aspx) message handler, and passes that on as *zDelta* to `OnMouseWheel`. It is exactly the same any old Windows API program would do.

Comment: Hmm, that's rather unlikely.   [Read this](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Mice-and-Pointing-Devices/Which-Software-for-M-U0007-Corded-Performance-Laser-Mouse/td-p/409282), follow up at superuser.com

Comment: @HansPassant: Link outdated!

Comment: So their forums suck as well, color me surprised.  Use archive.org if you still haven't read it after a year and a half :)

Comment: @HansPassant: I already knew about Wayback Machine. On there, the most recent "legible" snapshot is http://web.archive.org/web/20131006075731/http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Mice-and-Pointing-Devices/Which-Software-for-M-U0007-Corded-Performance-Laser-Mouse/td-p/409282